# Running C# application when .net framework is disabled

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I am developing one application which needs to be run on Windows 7, 8 and all recent WinOS'es. The problem is that on Win7 .net 3.5 is enabled by default but if the user disables it he won't be able to run my application. Plus on Windows 8 is disabled by default.

What are my options here?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: create an intelligent installer?

Comment: you need to setup prerequisite

Comment: There is no way to "disable" .NET. It simply might not be installed.

Comment: I can only really see two options; somehow notify the user to install 3.5, or run it using a [mono bundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime#Bundles).

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes, Kind of  ;). Thing is if it's disabled or not installed we should enable or install it accordingly

Comment: @JohnSaunders You can disable the .net framework on windows 7. and maybe on windows 8 too

Comment: @GaneshS Link some articles or knowledgebase to disable .Net

Comment: Most installers (Wix, installaware) have the ability to test for .Net versions during the install, and install accordingly.

Comment: "Disabling" .NET would cause a whole slew of applications to not work... including some that are preinstalled with Windows.

Comment: Clarification: My above comment relates to the OSes the OP has stated. It simply has been a pre-requisite to have the .NET Framework installed for as long as I can remember .. (XP SP 2 does too I think .. ?).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead he may be talking about unchecking the .Net framework in `Windows Features`

Comment: @paqogomez If I write my application in .net and if .net framework is installed how will application install the .net?? #confused

Comment: These install packages that I mentioned, first test for .net versions, before your application is installed.  If the prereq's are met, then they install your app, otherwise, they fix it, or prompt the user, depending on how you set them up.

Comment: @paqogomez You simply cannot remove .NET entirely from newer operating systems. You can only turn on or off various features of each.. try it.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Or give some examples of install packages.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I am well aware.  Only suggesting that is what he might be talking about when he says "disable".  [There are tutorials for doing such a silly thing.](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/uninstall-net-framework-from-windows-7/)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead You meant to say If I write .net application build it and run it on machine where .net framework is disabled it will run, right? Is that what you want to say.

Or maybe I target for .net 2.0 that will run on all OSes?

Comment: [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) is an free installer package that you can use to program an installer for your application. Learning this will take time.  Start reading.

Comment: There is no such thing as "disabling" .NET. If you believe there is, then you should provide a link describing this.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, did you see my [link](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/uninstall-net-framework-from-windows-7/)?

Comment: Are you blind? That's about _uninstalling_ .NET, not _disabling_ it.

Comment: Nope, not blind, clearly the message is getting lost.  Ganesh, enjoy Wix, Happy New Year.

Comment: @JohnSaunders There are two ways mentioned in that link one disables it, one uninstalls it. 
From that link -

`Doing it won’t uninstall it completely, rather it is simply disabled. To uninstall it you will need a 3rd party portable tool called .NET Framework Cleanup Tool`

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still pretty sure that link is just wrong. I've never in over a decade heard that the .NET Framework can be "disabled".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Is this link to Microsoft also wrong?  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-windows-features-on-off#1TC=windows-7  Turning off a feature does not uninstall the feature, and it does not reduce the amount of hard disk space used by Windows features.

Comment: @GaneshS: the MS article is not wrong, it's simply not relevant. It says nothing about disabling .NET Framework. Just because some Windows Features can be disabled doesn't imply that _all_ Windows Features can be disabled.

Comment: @paqogomez The link is at best incomplete.  If you open up the .NET 3.51 it is just two WCF features.  And .NET 4.0 is not listed at all.

Comment: @Blam, I didnt consider this question to be at all about how to disable or enable .NET or if it was even possible.  I considered this question about how to get an app to run if .net wasnt installed.   I provided the link only to offer some possible clarity for the OP's use of the word "disable".

Comment: @paqogomez How is that link clarity?   You blindly posted with zero vetting.

Comment: @Blam, Thank you for pointing that out.  Clearly, in hindsight, it was a mistake.  Its the dwelling on it that astounds me at this point.

Comment: @paqogomez Oh so you finally vet and I am dwelling?

Comment: "Dwelling"? Your question remains here for people to read for all Eternity. Delete your question and nobody will "dwell" on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall .NET library. You can't disable it. If you mean disabling **Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN vX.X** service, don't worry. Your application will run without the service.

By the way, you can create an installer which installs .NET Framework and then your application. For example you can create an installer with InnoSetup which installs .NET Framework **silently** and then installs your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried simple application it runs when after disabling .net framework on Windows 7 but on Windows 8 something looks different.

Additionally, when we disable, say .net 3.5, .net 2.0 still exists but on Windows 8 it's not the case

Answer (score 1):

As many of the comments states I never heard of anything called Disabling .NET framework. Only option you might have to think of is whether target user machine has .NET Framework installed or not. If you are using Windows Installer to deploy the application set up itself check it for you, Prior to the installation installers checks if the target machine has prerequisite .Net Framework installed, if not it will abort the installation asking the user to install the framework first.

`Windows Installer Prerequisites`

Installer Properties > Prerequisites

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you insist writing your app in C#, then you have to force your users to enable .NET. A feasible workaround is to write your app in another language (C++, Python and so on). Anyway you need to discuss with your end users, and there is little help you can get from StackOverflow.